# HDFS path in user defined function of Pig Latin

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have the following User Defined Function programmed in Java language:

I defined FileWriter but an error message appear after the execution.

The program:

`outputFile = new FileWriter("hdfs://NaeNode:9000/input/SG.csv",true);
 fw = new BufferedWriter(outputFile);`

*Caught error from UDF: trial.obvious_guess [hdfs:/NaemNode:9000/input/SG.csv (No such file or directory)]*

How can I fix this issue, since I am using [pig -x MapReduce fie.pig] on execution

Comment: if we modified the path like  this: hdfs:\\NameNode:9000\\input\\SG.csv, then the error will disappear, but Java can't write any thing in the SG.csv file.

Comment: Please avoid words in capitalised letters. This means screaming and this is very bad style for forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store in HDFS, you must use FSDataOutputStream.

FileSystem.create returns FSDataOutputStream.

See the code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FSDataOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        Path path = new Path("hdfs://NaeNode:9000/input/SG.csv");
        String data = "data";
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        if (!fileSystem.exists(path)) {
            fout = fs.create(path); 
        } else {
            fout = fs.append(path)
        }
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(fout)
        );
        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code, data is inconsistence, which means, each set of data read (bag), file contents always change. so after running the udf, only few lines are stored in the file, while the rest of the files are overwritten.

Comment: I modified it to append if the file exists. Check out the modified code.